# Multiple disks on different locations in Vagrant

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v, vagrant, windows-server

I have a Windows Server on which I want to create 3 virtual machines with Vagrant. Each one should have two disks attached: the primary one - SSD with 50GB of storage space and another one - HDD with 100GB. How would I configure custom paths for my disks and correctly attach them to the VM? For clarification I am using Hyper-V.

I tried using this configuration but it ended up not working correctly.

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    (1..3).each do |i|
        vm_name = "vm-#{i}"

        config.vm.define vm_name, primary: true do |oph|
            oph.vm.box = "roboxes/ubuntu2204"
            oph.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "Virtual Switch", ip: "1.2.3.#{i}"
            oph.vm.hostname = vm_name

            oph.vm.disk :disk, size: "50GB", name: "main", primary: true, type: "SSD", path: "C:\\path\\#{vm_name}.vhdx"
            oph.vm.disk :disk, size: "100GB", name: "backup", type: "HDD", path: "D:\\path\\#{vm_name}.vhdx"

            oph.vm.provider "hyperv" do |hyperv|
                hyperv.linked_clone = false
                hyperv.cpus = 8
                hyperv.memory = 16384 # 16 GB
                hyperv.maxmemory = 32768 # 32 GB
                hyperv.vmname = vm_name
                hyperv.auto_stop_action = "Save"
                hyperv.auto_start_action = "Nothing"
            end
        end
    end
end
```